# Why does updating gridview also update the datasource (datatable)? If its 2 way then which is better for iteration?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datatable in code. And the datagridview in the Ui.

In code I have done gridviewName.DataSource = dtTable1

Now in the UI I can see gridview populated with the table data. In the UI gridview I can update the cell values and/or delete the data rows. Upon doing any changes to the gridview, the changes automatically flow back into the data table.

I am bit confused at this point because I had thought it is a 1 way connection from data table into datagridview. Is this 2 way by design? If yes, then subsequently if I want to perform an operation per row, like send an email per row, then it is recommended to iterate over the gridview or the data table?

Comment: I found then when assigning a data source, I would query the data table, then create a new instance of the data (in a list, NOT Enum or iQueryAble) I had gotten and assign it as a data source. That way you have one-way connection, can iterate over the data in memory rather than accessing the data source again.

Comment: The datatable is also in memory. I didn't get your point.

Comment: Hi John I didn't understand your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 2 way data flow is by design; it makes creating applications a lot easier. If you don't want your user to edit a grid you make the grid read only, but typically you show data to a user, you let them edit it and save it. That would get a lot more hard work if you made data binding a one way thing the grid is connected to the datatable directly; it doesn't copy the data it finds into its own internal data array

Always loop over the datatable, read it and edit it directly; the grid will update accordingly; always avoid looping over the datagridview. As the embodiment of model-View-controller your code should manipulate the model (datatable) not try and manipulate the model via the view/controller that is intended for the user (the datagridview)

If you add a DataSet type file to your project and design a strongly typed datatable inside it your life gets easier. Your code looks like:

```
foreach(var r in soneDataset.EmailQueueDataTable){

  mailer.Send(r.From, r.To, r.Subject, r.Message, r.RetryAttempts);

}
```

With a standard datatable everything is done with string column names or worse, ordinal positions and needs casting:

```
foreach(DataRow r in EmailQueueDataTable.Rows){

  mailer.Send((string)r["From"], (string)r["To"], (string)r["Sujbect"], (string)r["Message"], (int)r["RetryAttempts"]);

}
```

Intellisense won't help you with the column names either; you'll only find out at runtime that I made a typo in Subject

Comment: Caius - the datatable is not available in button click event. Where as datagridview is available.

Comment: If the datagridview is available and it is bound to the table, then the datatable is available because it's conencted to something that is available `var dt = datagridViewWhatever.DataSource as DataTable`

Comment: Ok I was thinking about making the datatable dt global. Thanks for this tip.